# Can I create a wildcard ssl cert for a subdomain?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have created my own CA cert, and created a wildcard ssl cert for `*.domain.com`.

But we use a lot of sub-domains of the form abc.xyz.domain.com, and I can't seem to create a wild card that will work with this.

`*.domain.com` fails on abc.xyz.domain.com, and creating a wildcard for `*.*.domain.com` didn't seem to work.

Is there a way to do this, or do I need to create a wildcard for each subdomain?

Answer (score 1):

For the record, it doesn't look like it's possible to have *.* as a wildcard.

We ended up renaming our hosts from abc.xyz to abc-xyz, and then the wildcard worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could create ssl certificate for *.xyz.domain.com

Comment: That's an option, but I'm hoping there is a way to have all subdomains recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to apply wildcard as * . * .domain.com, wildcard can secure unlimited sub domain name on the "Same Domain Name" that can secure either *.domain.com or as Alex said *.xyz.domain.com, in both the term only the value of aster-risk can be changed not the other top or second level domain.

And applying wild card to each sub domain is expensive, you can use SAN SSL if you have limited sub domains, as SAN SSL can secure up to 25 different domains, servers or IPs.

Comment: The cost isn't really going to be a factor here as the certificates are being self signed with a trusted CA