# SSL wildcard certificates and "www" sub-subdomains

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, wildcard-subdomain

I've got a wildcard SSL certificate for `*.example.com`.

I'm using Nginx, and redirecting all traffic for HTTP to HTTPS, and also rewriting the URLs to remove a www subdomain (if there is one).

So it has,

1. `http://subdomain.example.com`       ---> `https://subdomain.example.com`
2. `http://www.subdomain.example.com`   ---> `https://subdomain.example.com`
3. `https://www.subdomain.example.com`  ---> `https://subdomain.example.com`
4. `https://subdomain.example.com`      ---> `https://subdomain.example.com`

However, since my cert is for `*.example.com`, case 3 gets an SSL error in chrome ("This is probably not the site that you are looking for!"), but if you click through it gets redirected and all is well.

I understand why, since the initial connection is for HTTPS with a www (2 levels of subdomains), which doesn't match what is on the wildcard certificate.

I thought a solution would be to get an additional cert for `*.*.example.com` to cover `www.*.example.com`.  But it seems like that won't work.
I spoke to agents from Namecheap and Comodo, and both said `*.*.example.com` was not possible.

I also came across [this article](https://support.quovadisglobal.com/KB/a60/will-ssl-work-with-multilevel-wildcards.aspx) that states:

> **Will SSL work with multilevel wildcards?**
>
> With the distribution of Firefox 3.5, all major browsers allow only a single level of subdomain matching with certificate names that contain wildcards, in conformance with RFC 2818.
>
> In other words the certificate `*.mydomain.com` will work for `one.mydomain.com` or `two.mydomain.com` but NOT `one.two.mydomain.com`.

Is there a solution to this? To be able to cover `www.*.example.com`?

Comment: sort of similar to http://serverfault.com/questions/520168/can-i-create-a-wildcard-ssl-cert-for-a-subdomain but defeats my purpose of getting a wildcard subdomain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildcard certs only go one level deep. You will need to get a wildcard that also has subject-alternate names for all `www.<subdomain>.example.com` sites. This will allow the redirection to happen.

Any solution other than putting valid certs on the two-level-deep subdomains will not work, because the SSL handshake will always happen before any redirection or re-writing.

Comment: I've read about SAN before and understand it can cover multiple domains. Can it also do something like www.*.example.com?
The reason I needed a wildcard, was because I am giving out subdomains to users.
Thanks

Comment: It cannot. You can add SANs to wildcard certain but you can never have a wildcard in the middle like you want. This is why you almost never see anyone with the setup you are describing.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking around for other sites that have setups similar to mine, like <subdomain>.uservoice.com, and they also get the warning I am trying to avoid.

Comment: This is similar to the problem that Stack Exchange itself is trying to solve. They have `meta.<site>.stackexchange.com` and haven't come up with a good way to handle SSL. I think they're probably going to throw a lot of money and some config management tools at it to automatically provision and install new certs when new sites are added. A single-cert solution just doesn't really exist for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Small workaround is to rewrite URLs before establishing SSL connection, but you will never get https://www.subdomain.mydomain.com working without a warning before you get certificate for this domain name. Something like that:

```
server {
 listen 111.222.333.444:80;
 server_name www.subdomain.mydomain.com;

 rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
}

server {
 listen 111.222.333.444:443
 server_name subdomain.mydomain.com
 ssl on;
 ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is how wildcard certs work. They only work on first-level subdomains as you're seeing. To work around this, you'd want to use a PTR record to point www.subdomain.domain.com to subdomain.domain.com and it should be invisible to the server.

Comment: A PTR record isn't going to help anything here. I think you may have meant CNAME, but even that won't help. DNS solutions can't fix this.