# only www.*.domain.com certificate for wildcard domain

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, wildcard-subdomain

I haven found a answer to the question from 2013 but is this answer still valid with SNI.

[SSL wildcard certificates and trailing 'www'](https://serverfault.com/questions/520556/ssl-wildcard-certificates-and-trailing-www)

Is it possible to have a certificate or SAN with www.*.domain.com which works with current Browsers?

example:

plain www.subdomain1.domain.com/ => secure www.subdomain1.domain.com/
plain www.subdomain2.domain.com/ => secure www.subdomain2.domain.com/

I know how to configure nginx to accept the domain but I'm not sure if the browser accept the certificates.

Many thanks for answers.

Comment: No, browsers won't accept such certificate. Wildcard sign is allowed only at left position and only once. Configurations such `www.*.domain.com` and `*.*.domain.com` are not allowed.

Comment: As per Wildcard SSL security policy, it only allows you to secure *.domain.com or *.subdomain1.domain.com, but it won't allow you to secure www.subdomain1.domain.com.